# How can I mimic Node.js's require function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, modularity

In node.js you can write:

```
var lib = require('lib');
```

but in Ruby the require function simply runs the code in the file and `true` is returned.

Currently, I'm using a very dirty solution:

main.rb:

```
$stuff = []
require './file1.rb'
require './file2.rb'
# and so on
```

file1.rb:

```
$stuff << something
```

and so on.

How can I eliminate the use of a global variable?

eg:

main.rb:

```
$stuff = []
$stuff << cool_require './file1.rb'
# etc
```

file1.rb:

```
exports.what = something
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the biggest errors when working with a language, is trying to make the language working like a different one.

Ruby is not NodeJs, there are features built-in into each language that are unique to the language and cannot be reproduced easily.

In other words, there is no way to implement the NodeJS require behavior in Ruby because in Ruby there is no notion of export. When you require a file, every method/class included in the required file are made available to the scope.

In Ruby there are objects and method visibility. The way you have to make a method visible or not is to declare it as public or private/protected.

Comment: I couldn't think of a better title. What I really want to know is how can I eliminate the global variable.

Comment: You should make more clear what you are using the global variable for. If file1 uses a variable that is part of main, the code is broken by design because you have a circular dependency between main and file1. Please make a practical example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: +1 for the opening line. Ruby isn't Node.js and shouldn't be treated that way. Ruby has origins in Perl, but we seldom write things as we would in Perl, even when it's syntactically possible. Learn to use Ruby in its idiomatic way. Your code will fit in to the eco-system better. Plus consider whether your insistence on writing Ruby in a Node.js fashion would enhance your desirability to a potential employer. I doubt they'd be impressed if you can't write code that fits the "norm".

Answer (score 1):

Well, first consider that Ruby is not Node.js. As Simone Carletti said, there are some features that are unique to each language. Sometimes it's good to take from other language but sometimes it's bad.

#### There are few things that you must keep in mind:

- `meth` is method invocation, to pass method you use `method` method: `method(:meth)` or package it into module/class
- you can use class/module by assigning it to some 2nd variable:

  `class A;
    def self.aa; puts 'aa'; end;
  end;
  New_a = A;
  New_a.aa # aa;`
- `eval` is dangerous method(you can evaluate unknown code)

#### Method:

Here is one way you can do. It is not idiot-proof tough. It is not 100% safe(`eval`). :

file1.rb:

```
Module.new do
  def self.meth1
   42
  end
  def self.meth2
    'meth2'
  end
end
```

- This file contain module with 2 methods.
- I am using `Module.new` because it returns object that you want. You can assign it later into variable/constant.
- I am using `self.meth*` so you don't have to `include` but run instantly it like this: `module_name.meth1()`

req.rb:

```
def cool_require name
  eval(File.read name)
end

Some_variable = cool_require('req.rb') 

puts Some_variable.meth1 # 42
puts Some_variable.meth2 # meth2
```

- `cool_require` reads filename(argument `name`) and `eval`uate it(it is just like you would type it in irb/pry)
- `Some_variable` is constant. It won't disappear that easily.
- 2 last line is how it works. As fair I remember, that's how node.js' require works.